# Converting a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type created an out of range value

Tags: sql-server

I'm using a script generated with the command "Tasks/generate a script" in SSMS.

When I tried to launch the script in another database I got this error for certain lines:

> Msg 242, Niveau 16, État 3, Ligne 21681
>   Converting an nvarchar data type to a datetime data type created an out of range value.

and this is the example of line which caused the error

```
 CAST(N'2020-03-26 22:03:25.013' AS DateTime)
```

I understand it is a problem of the type of the column but I'm using another base with the same architecture.

Any help? And thanks

Comment: What are the **values** in your table that cause this error??

Comment: If this works in one server but not another, maybe that server has a different default date format, and maybe your date strings are not in the correct format to be parsed automatically. See https://www.technothirsty.com/change-default-date-format-in-sql-server/ . Hard to be sure because you didn't provide any sample data, or any information about the environment(s) in which you are executing the script.

Comment: @marc_s this value fo xample CAST(N'2020-03-26 22:03:25.013' AS DateTime)

Comment: Can you try if this works? `CAST(N'2020-03-26T22:03:25.013' AS DateTime)`  (note the `T` as delimiter between date and time portions)

Comment: @marc_s thanks but my problem is that the file contains 100 000 lines So i need a function to add T to all the lines

Comment: Can you cast as `DATETIME2(3)` instead? `CAST(N'2020-03-26 22:03:25.013' AS DATETIME2(3))` should work just fine (I believe)

Answer (score 1):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not. Also, the `DATETIME` datatype is particularly picky about how to be represented as a string literal.... other datatypes are much less of a problem!

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible